# Spring multiple beans: Are there other precedence annotations besides `@Primary`?

Tags: java, spring

I will start by explaining my situation. Our applications are divided into a shared project (containing code for all projects) and the specific applications. In the shared project we have an `interface` together with its implementation

```
public interface Provider
{
...
}

@Bean
public class ProviderImpl implements Provider
{
...
}
```

In some applications we need to change the default implementation, so we define another `Bean`

```
@Bean
@Primary
public class ApplicationProviderImpl implements Provider
{
...
}
```

I would like to remove the need to annotate every application-specific implementation with `@Primary`, so other developers can just provide theire bean implementations as failsafe as possible.

Are there other Annotations beside `@Primary` which decide which bean implementation is used? Qualifiers could help, but will make it more error-prone in my opinion.

Comment: why not use @Qualifier for your beans ?

Comment: Your `ProviderImpl` could use some [`@Conditional`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations) to only be instantiated, if no other bean of `Provider` type is being loaded. [@ConditionalOnMissingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html#:~:text=Annotation%20Type%20ConditionalOnMissingBean&text=%40Conditional%20that%20only%20matches%20when,met%20by%20the%20same%20bean.) seems to be what you are looking for

Comment: The beans are used in the shared and the application project. So there must be a `@Qualifier` at every `@Autowired`. A lot of work. Furthermore I think this will fail when only the default bean is available, which has no `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBaumer, I transfered your comment into an answer so others find it more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @XtremeBaumer I got a nice solution:

```
// in shared project
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Provider.class)
public class ProviderImpl implements Provider
{
...
}
```

This basically results in the opposite of `@Primary`.

Comment: I would be interested, if there were two beans with the same `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotations, what would happen? Spring should have no possibility to decide which to use, would it throw an exception?

Comment: Note that this is intended to use in spring boot auto configuration; if it is used in a different context it usually works, but we did run into problems having to do with the beans' loading order (which is guaranteed to be correct in spring boot auto config).

Answer (score 0):

Since the comment has a length limit, let me put it here, Re: @Mathias "if there were two beans with the same @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotations..."

Spring doesn't provide dedicated bean overriding mechanism, but does support rich bean-selection approches on injection side. One of them is ObjectProvider. Suppose you have 3 beans for your Provider interface:

```
@Bean
@Order(10000)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Provider enterpriseProvider() {
    return new EnterpiseWideProvider();
}

@Bean
@Order(5000)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Provider productLineProvider() {
    return new ProductLineProvider();
}

@Bean
@Order(1000)
public Provider productProvider() {
    return new MyProductProvider();
}
```

Now use ObjectProvider<Provider> instead of Provider on injection side (constructor injection, ObjectProvider<Provider> as a parameter):

```
this.provider = objectProvider.orderedStream().findFirst(); // 'productProvider'
```